# Head segmentation from depth image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

What algorithm can I use to segment head out of top view depth image? The height of head may vary and different images have different intensity for head.

[16bpp Sample Depth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VJaE.png)

Comment: I've clarified in your question that the attached image is a 16bpp one (and so won't be trivially viewable for many people), but you could really do with providing a quick visualisation in a more friendly format to give people a better idea of what you want without having to fire up external tools.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite 2.5D/3D feature descriptor for registration and recognition is the spin image.
Other recent advances (all searchable on-line for suitable algorithims) include: 3D-Sift, Fast Point Feature Histogram, Normal Aligned Radial Features (NARF), Depth Kernel Descriptors. Older methods simply used surface properties such as curvature and edges to identify region patches.
Which is best? Depends on what you want to find, viewpoint invariance, additional clutter, etc.